# Syntax to check if there is data in table according to a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQL syntax where I return some data for a user. Is any better way of executing the following query, where I just want to know if there is data for `user X` in `category y`.

```
$search_sql = " SELECT id FROM sn_news WHERE id_category = $category AND id_client = $client ";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);    
$search_query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);

if($search_query_result)
{
    $search_result = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $search_result = FALSE;
}
```

I just what to get a `TRUE` if there is data for my query, or a `FALSE` if not, to later use that result in a `$.post()` to know what to print out and what to remove.

Note: I haven't tried the code, but I guess it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns `FALSE` when there is no row to fetch. You can check the return value like this:

```
$search_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query) !== FALSE;
```

Tell you what, this is essentially the same as what you are doing in your original code.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA, your solution is really simple and effective

Answer (score 3):

```
$search_sql = " SELECT id FROM sn_news WHERE id_category = $category AND id_client = $client ";
if ($search_query = mysql_query($search_sql))
{
    $search_result=(mysql_num_rows($search_query) ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

or, to actually retrieve the data too

```
$search_sql = " SELECT id FROM sn_news WHERE id_category = $category AND id_client = $client ";
$search_query_result=array(); // initialise empty return array
if ($search_query = mysql_query($search_sql))
{
    switch mysql_num_rows($search_query)
    {
        case 0:
            $search_result=FALSE;
            break;
        default: // got something
            $search_result=TRUE;
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)
            {
                $search_query_result[]=$row;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This checks the number of returned rows and sets the variable accordingly using the useful little side effect that a integer value of 0 is equivalent to FALSE.

I would also add some checks to see if the query worked in the first place. It's always useful to check in case you've got a syntax error in your SQL or there's a problem with the server itself (see my code)

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be like `mysql_num_rows($search_query)` and not `mysql_num_rows($search_query_result)` ?

Comment: @w0rldart - yup. My bad. Sorted it now